# How to evaluate a multivariable function in MATLAB with a vector argument

Tags: function, matlab, math, matlab-figure, numerical-methods

I would like to know if in MATLAB there is a way to evaluate f(v) with f a handle function of 'n' arguments (x1,...,xn) and v a vector of length 'n' (v1,...,vn) since f(v) would throw error.

The correct syntax: f(v(1),v(2),...v(n))
but this is not easy in the example below

I'm trying to deduce a code to obtain the jacobian matrix of a function F : R^n -----> R^n
so i'm using the three point derivative formula. F is a cell array and for each row i'm taking f=F{i} as my function in which i want to evaluate the derivative with respect to each variable x(j).
My problem arises when I want to evaluate the difference f(x_adelantado)-f(x_atrasado)

x_adelantado, x_atrasado are vectors but the arguments of f should be written as:

f(x_adelantado(1),x_adeltantado(2), ... ,x_adelantado(n))

is there a way to evaluate f(v)? with f a handle function of 'n' arguments and v of length 'n'

```
function [J] = Jacobiano(F,x0)
%#JACOBIANO
%  calcula el Jacobiano de la funcion F evaluado
%  en x0 (punto de R^n).
%   Inputs:                 F --------- Arreglo de funciones anónimas,
%                                       continuas y derivables en x0
%                           x0 -------- Punto de evaluacion del jacobiano

h=0.01;
n=length(F);
m=length(x0);

for i=1:n                       %me paro en una fila del jacobiano
    f=F{i};                     %todas las derivadas parciales corresponden a la i-esima funcion

    for j=1:m
        x_adelantado=x0;
        x_adelantado(j)=x0(j)+h;
        x_atrasado=x0;
        x_atrasado(j)=x0(j)-h;
        
        J(i,j)=(1/(2*h))*(f(x_adelantado)-f(x_atrasado));
    end

end
end
```

Comment: If `v` is a structure of length `n`, then `f(v{:})` is equivalent to `f(v1,v2,...,vn)`.

Comment: Perhaps @obchardon meant a cell array, rather than a structure. For example: `v = [10 20 30]; v_cell = num2cell(v); f(v{:})` is the same as `f(v(1), v(2), v(3))`. More information about this [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, a cell array, my bad.